# Filtering out anchor tags in a string

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

I need to filter out anchor tags in a string.  For instance,

```
Check out this site: <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a>
```

I need to be able to filter out the anchor tag to this:

```
Check out this site: http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

That format may not be constant, either.  There could be other attributes to the anchor tag. Also, there could be more than 1 anchor tag in the string.  I'm doing the filtering in vb.net before it goes to the database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a simple regular expression that should work.

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

' ....

Dim reg As New Regex("<a.*?href=(?:'|"")(.+?)(?:'|"").*?>.+?</a>")
Dim input As String = "This is a link: <a href='http://www.stackoverflow.com'>Stackoverflow</a>"
input = reg.Replace(input, "$1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```